# Difference Private Endpoint vs Managed Private Endpoint

Tags: azure-synapse

Synapse uses the term [Managed Private Endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/synapse-workspace-managed-private-endpoints), but at the end it seems like they are typical endpoints.

Is there any difference between a Managed Private Endpoint and a Private Endpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference between a Managed Private Endpoint and a Private Endpoint.

A Private Endpoint is a network interface that uses a private IP address from your virtual network to connect you privately and securely to a service that's powered by Azure Private Link.

On the other hand, a Managed Private Endpoint is a private endpoint created in a Managed Virtual Network associated with your Azure Synapse workspace.
Azure Synapse manages these private endpoints on your behalf. You can create Managed private endpoints from your Azure Synapse workspace to access Azure services (such as Azure Storage or Azure Cosmos DB) and Azure hosted customer/partner services

**Reference:**

- [private
  endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-overview)
- [Synapse Managed private
  endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/synapse-workspace-managed-private-endpoints)